# Как подождать promise перед рендером в React js?

Tags: reactjs

Как подождать promise перед рендером в React js?

Используются сторонняя библиотека [prax](https://mitranim.com/prax/).
Так не работает:

```
class Index extends PraxComponent {
    async subrender({deref}) {
        console.log('catalog render')

        let categories_obj = await Api.getCategoryObj()

        return (<div>categories_obj</div>)
    }
}
```

Comment: В JS нельзя "подождать", привыкайте :) У пендеринга есть причины быть синхронным. Если сейчас рендерить нечего, рендерите ничего. Потом, когда результаты придут, отрендерите ещё раз.

Comment: спасибо, попробую